# Detect lowest Java version supported

Tags: java, sdk, intellij-idea, backwards-compatibility, radix

I'm working on a little Java app and I'm currently putting the installer together. This checks for perquisites, such as Java being installed, and prompts the user to download anything that's required.

I need to set a requirement for the minimum Java version I support (I'm building with 7). Is there a simple way I can detect what this would be? So if I'm using any classes etc. not available in earlier versions. BTW I'm using IntelliJ.

Comment: What sort of application is it?  Does it have a GUI?

Comment: *"minimum Java version I support (I'm building with 7)."*  As an aside, using Java 7 it is possible to create code compatible with previous versions.  It just takes some tweaking of compile time parameters and an rt.jar from the target version.

Comment: It sits in the system tray and listens for connections from an iOS app. It's got a couple of text entry views it pops up, made with swing.

Comment: Thanks. JWS sounds good. I'll take a look at it and see if it'll work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the entire 'system tray' complicates things, but..

1. For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.
2. The best way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html). (That script will do the 'version checking').

Comment: That works, if the end-user has a proper runtime installed of course, the browser plugin has not been systematically deactivated, the user is not using a browser that does not match the CPU architecture of the installed runtime (32/64 bits) and there are no issues with user system rights and the auto-updating hasn't broken the runtime installation. Alas, that is not as common as Sun wanted it to be when JWS was first designed :( Me personally, I'd only deploy applications with a minimized 32-bits runtime bundled with it. Its not perfect but it minimizes tech-support needs.

Comment: @Gimby  *"if the end-user has a proper runtime installed of course"*  That's complete nonsense.  It works just fine when no Java is installed.  Perhaps you should revisit the script and correct your misunderstandings before abandoning it.